# How to send a message in a specific channel with id

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I used replit database to save channel id
This is my code:
`client.channels.cache.get(db.get(args[1])).send(args[2]);`
and i get this error:

```
client.channels.cache.get(db.get(args[1])).send(args[2]);
                                                ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'send')
    at Client.<anonymous> (/home/runner/anonymesssendbot/index.js:44:49)
    at Client.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at Client.emit (node:domain:475:12)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (/home/runner/anonymesssendbot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js:34:18)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (/home/runner/anonymesssendbot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/home/runner/anonymesssendbot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:346:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/home/runner/anonymesssendbot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:478:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/home/runner/anonymesssendbot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:317:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/home/runner/anonymesssendbot/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:199:18)
repl process died unexpectedly: exit status 1
```

Comment: It means that `client.channels.cache.get(db.get(args[1]))` returns undefined. Maybe the ID stored in your database is wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that `db.get()` returns a promise which you cannot pass as a value. Try retrieving the value first and then get the channel. Something like

```js
const id = await db.get(args[1]);
const channel = client.channels.cache.get(id);
channel.send(args[2]);
```

There is also a possibility that the id is stored incorrectly in your server. So have a look at that. You could log the id to check if that is the case.

Comment: no this is not work
`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'send')
    at Client.<anonymous> (/home/runner/anonymesssendbot/index.js:46:13)`

Comment: Have you tried performing some steps to debug your issue? console.log() the id. If its undefined something is wrong while getting the data from the database.